# MyMonero / XMRWallet API documentation

Tags: wallet, api

I cannot run my own node for hardware reasons. But I need to validate / manage payments and create new addresses.

I would like to replace `monero-wallet-rpc` with a web based wallet.

But where can I find the API documentation to make `curl` requests to these wallet servers?

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot run my own node for hardware reasons.

You don't need to run your own node to run `monero-wallet-rpc` as it can connect to one of the many public nodes.

Just find a public node (i.e. https://moneroworld.com/#nodes), then launch `monero-wallet-rpc` with:

```
 --daemon-address arg    Use daemon instance at <host>:<port>
```

> But where can I find the API documentation...

MyMonero has API documentation: https://github.com/mymonero/hosted-monero-api-spec

XMRWallet does not, but I should add, many users have questioned if it's a scam anyway.